# How can I prevent post variables from appearing in the Yii2 log when I call warning() or info()?

Tags: php, security, yii, error-handling, yii2

I am maintaining an app built in Yii2, and I want to use Yii::warning() to write log messages. This is fine except when I'm logging events in the user login sequence.

The username and password are sent as POST variables. These are sensitive information which should not be captured in a log file.

```
$errorno = ldap_errno($this->link);
$errorstr = ldap_err2str($errorno);
Yii::warning("LDAP error: $errorno: $errorstr");
```

The above code causes a log warning to appear, containing my ldap error messages, but that warning contains a full stack trace and POST variables.

Even if the warning is only written when there is a problem with the LDAP connection, it could contain any user's credentials at that time, from server admin to CEO.

How can I log warnings for authentication related events in Yii without getting a full stack trace and dump of POST fields?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure what PHP superglobal variables are exported to the log for each log target. In your config file, e.g.:

```
'log' => [
    'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
    'targets' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
            'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            'logVars' => ['_GET', '_POST', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_SESSION', '_SERVER'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

The default setting equivalent when the `logVars` property is omitted is shown in the example above.

Comment: This would work great except I want to only suppress the info for a specific log message, not the whole log file.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo: since the environment variables are written into log by page load and not by log message, that is not achievable (without modifying the Yii codebase). The best what you can do is turn it on / off dynamically for a page load depending on some parameters.

Comment: How about `Yii::$app->log->flush()`, then modify `logVars` to exclude `_POST`, then log your error, then `flush()` again, then revert your change to `logVars`?

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but theoretically, couldn't we just configure an alternate logger class to use that has all the `logVars` disabled for when we want to log a message manually without all the extra stuff but the standard logs would still have it?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid sensitive data leaking in logs, you can simply mask any variable in log files, and for any kind of level not only warnings.

```
'log' => [
    'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
    'targets' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
            'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            'maskVars' => [
                // current vars in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Target.php::$maskVars
                '_SERVER.HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
                '_SERVER.PHP_AUTH_USER',
                '_SERVER.PHP_AUTH_PW',

                // Filter and mask any POST vars. Examples:  
                //      '_POST.add_var_name_here'
                //      '_POST.your_form_name.your_field_name'
                // see: vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Target.php::$maskVars
                // see: vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Target.php::getContextMessage()

                '_POST.LoginForm.email',
                '_POST.LoginForm.password',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Now practice, how to determine and set **maskVars**. Suppose you see in your logs something like:

```
$_POST = [
    'LoginForm' => [
        'email' => 'example@example.com'
        'password' => 'mysecretpassword'
    ]
]
```

To mask email and password, you just need to add `'_POST.LoginForm.email'` and `'_POST.LoginForm.email'` to **maskVars** config.

**PS**: In this way you can mask any sensible variable from globals:

```
'_SERVER.add_var_name_here',
'_FILES.add_var_name_here',
'_COOKIE.add_var_name_here',
'_SESSION.add_var_name_here',
'_POST.add_var_name_here',
'_GET.add_var_name_here',
```